# running a loop on vectors

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a set of data matrices, from which I retrieve eigenvalues as follows:

```
all_eigen <- sapply(all_matrices,eigen,only.values=FALSE)
```

so that

```
head(all_eigen[[1]]$values)
[1] 4160.357 4061.777 3865.349 3853.142 3838.621 3829.705
```

There is no problem there. However, when I try to convert each set of eigenvalues for follow-up analyses, like so:

```
for(i in 1:length(all_eigen)){
abs(all_eigen[[i]]$values) -> x[[i]]
length(x[[i]] -> n[[i]]
seq(from = min(x[[i]]) - 1,
        to = max(x[[i]]) +1, by = 0.01) -> eigenGrid[[i]]
}
```

I get one of the two following error messages:

```
Error in x[[i]] <- abs(all_eigen[[i]]$values) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

or

```
Error in x[[i]] <- abs(all_eigen[[i]]$values) : object 'x' not found
```

This should be a relatively straight-forward task, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. (If, instead, I make the conversions one at a time - x1 <- abs(all_eigen[[1]]$values) - then there is no problem.) Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: It's `R`. I made an edit to OPs post. It should be up soon.

Comment: Did you define a list `x`?

Comment: That seems to have done it. So you have to make an empty list to store results, I guess that's the lesson here. Thanks a bunch.